# c language print graph square x

Tags: c, while-loop

### Rules:

1.It must be made using C language;

2.Program must not contain  if , ||, &&, !;

3.Program must use while ()

This is killing me this day, I just can't figure it out.

### What the program should do:

if you input 5,it will print this:

```
xxxxx
xyyyx
xy1yx
xyyyx
xxxxx
```

if you input 6,it will print like this:

```
xxxxxx
xyyyyx
xy11yx
xy22yx
xxxxxx
```

So you know the output when you input 8,9 and so on.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Well,first answer what have you tried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a dump of a homework assignment that shows zero effort on the part of the OP.

Comment: I used if and for () to work it out and I just don't know how to solute it just with while().Anyone can help ?

Comment: already show in picture

Comment: @superqq I don't see any picture. Also, if you are planning to: Please don't show code via pictures. Use text and formatting.

Comment: @superqq ,Thats the output you want.We expect you to show the code you have used to print that.

Comment: so sorry,this is my first time use stackoverflow, and I was busy with my homework yesterday. I don't know how to paste the code on it.I will improve my skill about this at weekend. Thank you for all the ruru's concern.

Answer (score 0):

Since it very much sounds like homework, I'm not going to be overly specific.  But nonetheless, since your comment indicates you've solved this using `for` and `if`, a couple points should put you well on your way.

First, you can do anything with a `while` you can do with a `for` (and vice-versa)--the `for` just provides a handy place to initialize your counter variable and a handy place to increment it.  You can still do these things with your own lines of code.

Second, if your `if` statements have single conditions (i.e., without `||` or `&&`), you can often make a simple transition to using the [switch statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm).

Comment: 1. my if statement have multiple && an &&, so I don't know how to make it without if. 2.can't use switch statement .3.I will pose my own code here at weekend. It's too busy now. and thanks.